# Insert phone number into database

Tags: php

I have a input for user to enter phone number and I use `int();` before I insert it into database.

I insert some phone number 0398765899->398765899 into DB

PHP `int();` auto remove the first 0, it seems fine but I when I try

```
   $var=0177;
    echo $new=(int)$var;
```

in PHP file, the result become `127`

Comment: Why convert a phone number to an integer?  It's a string value, not a numeric value.

Comment: `$var=0177` is not an integer - it's an octal. take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: insert phone number as string as its coverting number in octal

Comment: Quick fix http://codepad.org/H80Tua57 . But as @Denis mention in his answer phone number is string . So you should handle it as string format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A phone number is a string; not a number. Think `1-800-FOO-BANG`.

Also, note they're not always formatted the same way. Examples:

- (123) 456 7890 or 123-456-7890 -- US
- (+33) 1 23 45 67 89 -- France

Comment: what if user tyep some text on top, like wa 098 ow 988

Comment: to add on to that - check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Comment: @user2178521: that's up to you to decide, much like it's up to you to decide which zip code formats are acceptable. (hint: there are dozens of zip code formats out there, and a few countries have no zip codes at all.)

Answer (score 1):

Use php filters:

```
filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work:

```
$var=0177;
echo $new=(int)$var;
```

Because PHP think this is an octal number. This works:

```
$var='0177';
echo $new=(int)$var;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because a number in the format `0ddd` is treated by PHP as an Octal number. That's why you get 127 after conversion to `int`.

also as @Denis suggests storing phone numbers as `int` is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

when you convert the value to integer it will remove the first zeros always,because zero has no significance at first place according to significant digits. you have to leave the number as a string.