# Regex to validate phone number pattern

Tags: regex

How can I construct regx to validate phone number? That is:

1. First digit must be 04 or 050 , length range between 8-13
2. First digit cannot be 43 or 44 , first digit must be 4 or 9 and length should be 8 digits

I have tried this pattern:

```
^[04,050]\\d{8,13}
```

Can any body help me?

Comment: One does not simply *try* to validate phone numbers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023765/insert-phone-number-into-database/17023851#17023851

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 3):

Let's break it down (hoping I understand correctly):

```
^               # Start of string
(?:             # Match one of the following:
 04\d{6,11}     # Either an 8-13 digit number starting with 04
|               # or
 050\d{5,10}    # an 8-13 digit number starting with 050
|               # or
 4[0-25-9]\d{6} # an 8 digit number starting with 4 but not 43 or 44
|               # or
 9\d{7}         # an 8 digit number starting with 9
)               # End of alternation
$               # End of string
```

Comment: I noticed you did thus before and I let it slide, but this time I'm going to pull you up: `(?:` does **not** mean "either", although saying so helps make your comments into a sentence, this fact carries no technical weight and may be misleading to novices.

Comment: @Bohemian: I'm aware of the potential for misunderstanding. I just don't know what to write instead that's both correct and understandable. How do you like the new version?

Comment: I respect your regex skills greatly, however the comments are just wrong. For starters, you are starting a group to allow an OR, that's what the bracket does, then you (unnecessarily) make it non-capturing with `?:`, presumably for "performance" reasons (optimising early?), then you introduce some or'ed terms. I would comment it basically like that

Comment: Hi Tim Pietzcker , thanks. It worked for me :)  This is what I expect ....  ^(?:04\\d{6,11}|050\\d{5,10}) and ^(?:4[0-25-9]\\d{6}|9\\d{7}) .   Thank you once again !!

Comment: @Bohemian: Well, that was the point of my "Either..." - you just wrote yourself that the bracket "allows the ORs". As for `(?:...)` vs. `(...)`, that's just a habit. I never use a capturing group if I don't want to capture its contents. Not because of optimization, but to clearly convey its purpose.

Comment: I would have just said `(?: # start of (non capturing) group`. Now, a serious comment - why have the group at all? Isn't it not needed? Won't the OR work anyway because it's "bracketed" by start/end of input?

Comment: @Bohemian: The group is necessary; otherwise you'd have `(^foo) | (bar) | (baz$)`.